# Query by Date not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to return search results for every document that was created on a day. Below is the query I use.

```
var query = Document.find({}).populate('contacts');
var gte = moment(req.query.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').startOf('Day');
var lte = moment(req.query.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').endOf('Day');
query.where('dates.createdAt').gte(gte).lt(lte);
```

This query works for some days but not all. I can't seem to understand the behaviour. Please help out.

The format of the date in the query string is `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Works for : `2016-04-16T00:02:30.065Z`
Does not work for: `2016-04-15T19:02:59.758Z`

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong because you don't initialize as `.utc()`, and MongoDB dates are stored in UTC:

```
var gte = moment.utc(req.query.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
var lte = moment.utc(req.query.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').endOf('Day');
```

And there is no need for the `startOf()` either.

If you don't construct like that, then the resulting `Date` object is skewed by the difference in the local timezone. Hence why you don't see the selection working where the hours would cross over dates.

Also if dates are coming in as `01/01/2016` then the format string would be `'DD/MM/YYYY'`, but one or the other is likely a typo in your question.